# How do I rewrite split() to preg_split()

Tags: php, split, preg-split

Here is my code that I want to update from 5.1 to 5.3 in php

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];

function findexts ($filename) 
{ 
$filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
$n = count($exts)-1; 
$exts = $exts[$n]; 
return $exts;
```

But I am very confused on how to do it

Comment: What error do you get? Tried just replacing `split` with `preg_split`?

Comment: Yes, "Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated"

Comment: Change `$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);` to `$exts = preg_split("[/\\.]", $filename);`

Comment: Hmmm, thank you, it's working now, before I had that code exactly and it said that my resources were invalid, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing

```
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);
```

to:

```
$exts = preg_split("[/\\.]", $filename);
```

Should work!

Comment: It should be $exts = preg_split("[\\.]", $filename);, as it is in your answer it doesn't recognize your regex.